# How to hit four notes in a single beat with 2 hands for drum

Tags: technique, practice, drums, drum-kits

Sometimes when i am given a drum score , there will be four notes in a single beat , How do i hit four notes in a single beat given I only have 2 hands ???

[image]

The only way i know to hit 4 notes in a single beat if the four notes are  : Bass Drum , Foot Hi-Hat  + any 2 other notes

I am sure I am missing something , can someone elaborate to me ??

Comment: I thought that the idea of having several lines on the 'stave' was to differentiate the drums/cymbals. If so, why would the , for instance, SC(splash cymbal), not be all written on the same line, and each have its own line. It would be easier to read, surely ?

Answer (score 6):

Well, LowTom (LT) and HiMidTom (HMT) with the Hands, open hihat (oH) with feet plays either mounted SC or strikes SC thru HMT in one stroke.

Comment: How do you play open Hi-hat with your feet ??

Comment: Open hi-hat with foot = stomp it like it's hot.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some drummers hold the stick in the middle and hit two drums at once, with each end of the stick. Doesn't look very easy though !

Why would anyone ask you to do this by the way ?  If it's a generated drum score of some sorct (eg for a drum machine) then perhaps explain that you're human ?

Comment: And cue drummer jokes ..

Comment: eg. You only ahve to punch the rhythm once into a drum machine .. etc ..

Answer (score 0):

The graphic you have shown us in not any sort of "drum score" that I've ever seen.  Where did it come from?

As a live drummer, you've got two hands and two feet.   As computer programmers we can write as many simultaneous sounds as we like of course.  Keeping to what's physically possible for a real player can be a good rule so as not to muddy up the texture, but there's no need to be over-pedantic about it.